# facebook graph explorer returns empty data array using marketing api

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I have an issue with the graph explorer when I try to test for insights data.

When I do

```
act_XXX/?fields=campaigns
```

It returns

```
{
  "campaigns": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "XXXX"
      },
      {
        "id": "XXXX"
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "before": "MjM4NDI1MTI2NzQ3NzAxMzEZD",
        "after": "MjM4NDI1MTI2NzQxNTAxMzEZD"
      }
    }
  },
  "id": "act_XXXX"
}
```

But when I do

```
act_XXX/insights
```

I returns an empty data array

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

It looks like I have set the correct permission, but I must be missing something?

Comment: which api version you use? And whether there is insight in your account? I think it's normal to return empty if no insight in your account, ..., no spend

Comment: I am using version 2.8 ... The campaigns is inactive, but shouldn't the endpoint at least return a name of the campaigns ?

Comment: I think you query like  act_<your_account_id>/insight, then it query insight of account, why it should return name of campaigns :)

Comment: When I make a PHP test script I have this

`'campaign_name' => null` so I know it should be in the returned result

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but if query like : act_<account_id>/insights?fields=campaign_name,account_name, it will return account name with some value, but no campaign name returned

Comment: act_<account_id>/insights?fields=campaign_name,account_name - that will also just return an empty data array

Comment: that's strange, because I just query in tools explorer, it returns account name but no campaign name on node act_xxx/insights

Comment: I suspect I am missing something, but I don't know what it could be

Comment: I should point out, that the campaigns have never been active and therefore have no insights data. Could that be it?

Comment: From my test, it should return account name but no campaign name even if account has no spend on that time range, I am not sure whether campaign active influences it.  Just for curious, why you care about campaign name if it has no insight, you could get campaign name with node graph.facebook.com/v2.8/<campaign_id>?fields=campaign_name too :)

Comment: I will use the campaign name from the call without insights. I was just unsure whether the app had permission the get insights because of the empty data array. I did expect to get fields returned, just with empty or null values.

Comment: I think Facebook API will return valid forbidden info if no permission to fetch insight from account, like below:  "message": "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.",   btw, I guess you should make sure to fetch insight with right permission, because it's impossible to fetch insights from others :)

Comment: What are you trying to retrieve, a list of campaigns with their insights? Then call `act_xxx/campaigns?fields=name,insights` (if your campaigns don't have any insights then it won't include `insights` property into the response). if your account has no insights then it will return an empty array when you call `act_xxx/insights`, just like you got.

Comment: @MortenHagh were you able to solve this? Also get empty insights data on sandbox no matter what I do.

Answer (score 0):

probably doesn't have any insight data for previous month as it only fetches last month insights

try using

```
act_XXX?fields=insights.time_range({"since":"2018-03-03","until":"2019-03-03"})
```